# HTTP request doesn't work on Local Network

Tags: reactjs, express, http, cors

I recently developed a FS web app using React, Express.js and PostgreSQL.

The configured server accepts requests from some addresses, including my local network address, shown in the terminal after starting the client (configured in the CORS options).

[image]

[image]

I can't understand why, when I'm on the computer and I visit the address `localhost:3000`, everything works correctly, but when I want to use the web app on mobile (visiting `192.168.0.102:3000`, found using `ipconfig`), the server is unable to execute the requests.

On address 192.168.56.1:3000 I can't see anything and i don't know why

On mobile I get this error:

`undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response.data')`

I think that error means that the request cannot be satisfied.

I tried looking for some help online, but no resources were helpful, I asked ChatGPT for help but he couldn't help me solve the problem either :(

Would anyone know how to help me solve this problem, so I can understand what to do in the future if it happens to me again?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I already tried putting '*' instead of the addresses, but this doesn't work anyway